# Issue with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ,FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have an application installed in my device. I am trying to launch this application A from the buttonclick of another application B using the following code:

```
Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("co.abc.android.test",
                    "co.abc.android.test.Abc");
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Following is my issue:

- I launch application A
- I press home button
- From application B's button onclick, I launch app A again
- Press return button to exit application A, which was now launched
  from app B
- Eventhough I exit the application A on pressing return button, I am again taken to the main activity of app A, which I had launched initially.

On referring for this issue, I have read in many places that using **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**  would resolve this. But since I call app A's intent from a place in which I have no access to its context, it gives me the following error.

```
01-01 00:09:54.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(283): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WindowManagerPolicy
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:884)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockScreen$DialerMethods.onTrigger(LockScreen.java:218)
    at com.android.internal.widget.multiwaveview.Dialer$2.run(Dialer.java:366)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$PolicyThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:752)
```

How can I resolve this issue, such that when I press the return button, I do not see the same activity(if launched before) again?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you initially launching app A? From the installer? Or from the list of available applications? After you launch app B and press the button to launch app A check how many instances of app A are running (using ddms dump device state or `adb shell dumpsys`)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding inside `onClick` method:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to launch another application is like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("co.abc.android.test", "co.abc.android.test.Abc");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(intent);
```

This simulates what Android does when the user selects the application from the list of available apps.

Assuming that "co.abc.android.test.Abc" is the root activity of that application (ie: the one with intent-filter `ACTION_MAIN/CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`) this will either start the application (if it isn't already running) or just bring the application from the background to the foreground (if it is already running).